# Format error on JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I keep getting errors while trying to format an object:

```
Object x= itr3.next();
       x=String.format("%02d",x);
```

Here is the error:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:3999)
```

Comment: I wiped out the comments here. I hope we can play nice from now on.

Comment: Earlier you said that x comes in to the file as an Object, could you expand on that?  How is `itr3` defined?

Answer (score 3):

`String.format("%02d",x)` expects the second argument to be an `int` (or an `Integer`), not an `Object`. Also, Java is not a script language to change types dynamically like x behaves as `int` and then as `String`.

Looks like you have a `String` with numeric content and you want to change this `String` to has a left padding 0. You can do it like this:

```
String x = ... //get your content as String
int theNumber = Integer.parseInt(x); //this will work if your x contains numeric value
x = String.format("%02d", theNumber);
```

Comment: If this is causing an error, the value could be a Double or Float.  This might help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: @JasonSperske since OP doesn't specify the content of `x`, I've assumed it is an integer value because tries to format using `%d` instead of `%f`.

Comment: I agree that is the best assumption, however putting a leading zero in front of a float is complicated.  Assuming the OP is still reading this, a valid format string for floats (assuming you wanted to drop the decimals) might be: `"%02.0f"`

Comment: @JasonSperske we won't be sure for sure since OP doesn't even provide any help to get better guidance =\.

Comment: And with that there might not be more to say about this question.  We fought valiantly, but in the end its up to the OP to use whatever makes sense.  I've seen people provoked less, and react stronger.  I can see how you've earned your 10.7K.

Answer (score -2):

Simple question, simple answer: .format() does not work on type Object or String, only integer.

Comment: This is actually the most valid answer to the question because Luiggi's answer, as written, returns an error

Comment: Actually that isn't true (about what format() accepts), [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) does take Objects, and the `.format()` is rather smart about using them.  Try this: `Object x = 7; System.out.println(String.format("%02d", x));` this will print `07`, now try this: `Object x = "7"; System.out.println(String.format("%02d", x));` this will throw your exception.  However if you try a format for strings like `Object x = "7"; System.out.println(String.format("%s", x));` then you are good :)

Comment: The issue you are finding comes from the `Formatter.class`, when told to format an Integer, it looks for an Object that it can cast to Integer (x in your code cannot)